# JSON Parse to Object Weired Results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I am parsing an json whose structure looks like this:

```
"records": [
        {
            "timestamp": "1604133302",
            "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "district": "Anantapur",
            "market": "Rayadurg",
            "commodity": "Maize",
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1604133302",
            "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "district": "Chittor",
            "market": "Chittoor",
            "commodity": "Maize",
        },
.... 
]
```

and This is the code i tried to parse to object i want to show them in optional buttions in html where people selects the state and city and all :

```
jsonFile.records.forEach(function (s) {
    let { state, district, market, commodity } = s;
    // states[state] = district;
    // states[state][district] = market
    // states[state][district][market] = commodity;
    
    states[state] = {
        [district]: {
            [market]: [
                [commodity],
            ]
        }
    };
});
```

It's replacing the last updates.

How to properly parse.

The object structure i want is like this:

```
{
   "myState":{
      "myDistrict":{
         "myMarket":[
            "commoditynames"
         ],
         "myMarketAnother":[
            "commoditynames"
         ]
      },
      "myDistrictAnother":{
         "myMarket":[
            "commoditynames"
         ],
         "myMarketAnother":[
            "commoditynames"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How can i parse this properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to push the result not replace in the final commodity array.

We can use `.reduce()`, we can iterate over every element of an array and can maintain a final state of result. Read more about it [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

On every iteration, we initialize our `result` with empty objects/array and then finally pushing the desired data.

```js
function fixJSONStructure(records = {}) {
  
  return records.reduce((result, record) => {
      let { state, district, market, commodity } = record;
      
      // initialize with empty object
      if (!result[state]) result[state] = {};
      if (!result[state][district]) result[state][district] = {};
      if (!result[state][district][market]) result[state][district][market] = [];
      
      // pushing a commodity instead of replacing
      result[state][district][market].push(commodity);
      
      return result;
  }, {});
}

records = [
        {
            "timestamp": "1604133302",
            "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "district": "Anantapur",
            "market": "Rayadurg",
            "commodity": "Maize",
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1604133302",
            "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "district": "Anantapur",
            "market": "Rayadurg",
            "commodity": "something else",
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1604133302",
            "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "district": "Chittor",
            "market": "Chittoor",
            "commodity": "Maize",
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "1604133302",
            "state": "Karnatka",
            "district": "Bangalore",
            "market": "foobar",
            "commodity": "baz",
        },
];
console.log (fixJSONStructure(records));
```

Comment: @Thank You very much, can you explain it bit ? and how can get only names of state in case to show in list

Comment: @Venktaish There is not much to explain, this is a very straightforward code. Still, I have tried to add an explanation. Please point out the line of code which is not clear for you. Regarding the question you posted in the comments, please first try on your own, and share the code you have written if you have any trouble. (hint: maybe look into [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set))

Comment: I used Object.keys() for that.